# Need to convert some set letters to set numbers

Tags: java

I have recently been given a large project by my I.T. Teacher, but I have run into a small problem with one of the sections. It may seem easy to you, but not for me.

so the task at hand here is: you're given a cellphone number, but not a normal one. You're given one like this `"082HOSpITL"` and the task is to take the set number or string and convert the letters to numbers. So this `"082HOSPITL"` will change to this `"082432567"`. Of course the numbers that the letters will change to have to be set, so for example `"H"` would be equal to `"1"`, or to make it more simple `"HIJ"` is equal to `"1"`. Therefore if `H` is contained the number will be `1`. There does not have to be a GUI so you can just use `System.out.println();`

If you could get a prototype running so that it would give me a good idea on what to do, that would be great

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you've tried? How are you attempting to label each letter numerically? People will be more inclined to help you if you show some of your own efforts first.

Comment: *BRB, going to do your homework for you.*

Comment: I'm really not interested in doing your prototypes without compensation.  There's a charge for professional development, you know.  In all seriousness:  you should either talk to classmates or your teacher when they get back.  We're not in a position to write your code for you or explain what you need to do.

Comment: If YOU could get a prototype running so that it would give you a good idea on what to do, that would be great.

Comment: Im in grade 11 and have gotten through the simplest things such as "String [] num={082HOSPTL, 082BRANDON}" and then counting them but i dont know how to get the position, i have tryed .indexOF that did work but im having trouble setting the positions to the if statments

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an alphanumeric phone number to digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462834/how-to-convert-an-alphanumeric-phone-number-to-digits)

Comment: @BrandonEggersglusz The thing is, there are many ways to approach this. For example, you could use the built-in function `replaceAll`.  Or you could create a new `String` by looping over the old one. However, your initial post hasn't shown your effort. All we're asking is for you to show the relevant code you have written in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Surprise your teacher with some regex:

```
    String num = "082HOSPITL";

    num = num.replaceAll("[HIJ]","1");
    // etc.

    System.out.println(num);
```

Comment: My god thank you so much man, i actually just got it working, but i have like 20 lines of code and you have 3, so take my upvote and thanks